# C++ error: Passing 'const' as 'this' array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting  `passing 'const Array' as 'this' argument of 'int& Array::operator[](int)'  discards qualifiers` when compiling under `Dev C++`. If I compile using `gcc` on `cygwin` I've got a few error messages of this type:

```
 error: extra qualification ‘Array::’ on member ‘Array’ [-fpermissive]
```

Can you tell me what is the reason for the error? I've spent a lot of time on this code and still can't make it work correctly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Array
{
      int *m_ptr;
      int m_size;
      public:
             Array(int sz)
             {
                       cout<<"constructor\n";
                       m_size = sz;
                       m_ptr = new int[sz];
             }
             ~Array()
             {
                     cout<<"Delete\n";
                     delete[] m_ptr;
             }
             int& operator[] (int j)
             {
                  cout<<"Operation []\n";
                  return m_ptr[j];
             }
             void Array::copy(const Array& ar)
             {
                  m_size = ar.m_size;
                  m_ptr = new int[m_size];
                  int *ptr = ar.m_ptr;
                  int j;
                  for(j = 0;j < m_size; j++)
                  m_ptr[j] = ptr[j];
             }
             Array::Array(const Array& ar)
             {
                                copy(ar);
             }

             void Array::print(const Array& ar)
             {
                  int i;
                  int len = ar.m_size;
                  for(i = 0;i < len;i++)
                  cout<<ar[i]<<"  ";
                  cout<<endl;
             }
};
int main()
{
    Array a1(10);
    Array a2(5);
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
          a1[i] = 1;
          if(i < 5) a2[i] = 2;
    }
    print(a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore,  the book I am reading also has the function

```
Array& operator= (const Array& ar) 
{ 
   delete m_ptr; 
   copy(ar); 
   return *this; 
}
```

I do not understand why do we need to use this function.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1**

You don't need the `Array::` in

```
void Array::copy(const Array& ar) { ... }
```

when the function is defined inside the class definition. It can simply be

```
void copy(const Array& ar) { ... }
```

You need the `Array::` part only when the function is defined outside the class definition.

**Issue 2**

In `print`, you have the line:

```
              cout<<ar[i]<<"  ";
```

Since `ar` is a `const` object and the `operator[]()` function is not a `const` member function, the compiler doesn't like it. What you should do is provide two overloads of the `operator[]` function -- one for `const` objects and one for non-`const` objects.

```
int& operator[] (int j)
{
   return m_ptr[j];
}

int operator[] (int j) const
{
   return m_ptr[j];
}
```

Then, you can use the array operator to access the elements of a `const` object as well as access and modify the elements of a non-`const` object.

Comment: Even `const int&` as a return type for the `const` overload, I'd say.

Comment: When executing I get a Aborted(Core dumped). In the book I am reading, they add the function 
Array& operator= (const Array& ar)
             {
                    delete m_ptr;
                    copy(ar);
                    return *this;
             }
I do not understand why do we need to use this function. How does it help us not to have the Aborted(Core dumped) message at the end of the execution?

Comment: @George, I suggest you ask another question with the fixed up code instead of trying to get answer to that in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
void Array::copy(const Array& ar)
```

to

```
void copy(const Array& ar)
```

The class scope qualifier is only needed for function definitions appearing outside of the class declaration.